# Office 365 Admin : Audit MSGraph requests in Office365 Security & Compliance

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, office365api

As an exchange admin, I want to audit Graph API calls

Under Office 365 Security and Compliance section, Audit Log Search, I can find audit logs for other components such as Power BI but nothing for Graph.

I tried using Exchange Mailbox Activities but I don't see any audit logs when I access/update meeting items using Graph API.

**Is there a way I can audit these calls?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To monitor the MSGraph app activities, you should check for 'Add OAuth2 Permission Grant' activity under Azure AD workload. But O365 Security & Compliance portal doesn't show the activities performed by Azure AD workload.

As a workaround, you shall use the [Search-UnifiedAuditLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance-audit/search-unifiedauditlog?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet.

sample code snippet for getting last month data

```
Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate 4/23/2019 -EndDate 5/23/2019 -Operations "AddOAuth2PermissionGrant"
```

If you would like to explore the activities using a GUI interface then you shall try the Office 365 auditing reports available in [AdminDroid Office 365 Reporter](https://admindroid.com).

Comment: could not find any operation with operationname as "AddOauth2PermissionGrant". I could find audit logs with operations as "UserLoggedIn", "Update", "MovedToDeletedFolder" etc. Am i missing any setting ?

Comment: couldn't find it in MS documentation as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office365/securitycompliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance#audited-activities. Please suggest

Comment: @rohit I am not sure about the letter case for the operation name. If you have performed that action at least in 90 days, then you can check it in AdminDroid.

Comment: @EmberFreak I tried downloading AdminDroid and checked office365 audit reports, could not find any thing related to oauth/graph access. Can you please guide where exactly to look in AdminDroid?

Comment: @RohitRaghuvansi You can see it OAuth2 Permission Grant report. You can also have a look at in [interactive demo](https://demo.admindroid.com/#/audit/azure/reports/20046/1/20)